# Unable to get Bootstrap Modal in Flask python app to display row data for editing and working

Tags: python, flask, modal-dialog, bootstrap-5, crud

I am stuck in my application creation. This is for CRUD operation of Categories.
Creation, Reading and Deleting working fine. But not able to get to work for updating Categories. Please help in edit functionality.
Following is my Code.

Code for pfm.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, redirect
from flask import *
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///pfm.db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


app.app_context().push()


class Categories(db.Model):
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cat_type = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    cat_group = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    subcat = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('base.html')


@app.route('/viewcategories', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def viewcat():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cat_type = request.form['cat_type']
        cat_group = request.form['cat_group']
        subcat = request.form['subcat']
        
        categories = Categories(cat_type=cat_type, cat_group=cat_group, subcat=subcat)
        db.session.add(categories)
        db.session.commit()
    category = Categories.query.all()
    return render_template('viewcategories.html', category=category)


@app.route('/edit/<int:sno>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(sno):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = Categories.query.filter_by(sno=sno).first()

        cat_type = request.form.get['cat_type', category.cat_type]
        cat_group = request.form.get['cat_group', category.cat_group]
        subcat = request.form.get['subcat', category.subcat]

        categories = Categories(cat_type=cat_type, cat_group=cat_group, subcat=subcat)
        db.session.add(categories)
        db.session.commit()

    return redirect('/viewcategories')


@app.route('/delete/<int:sno>')
def delete(sno):
    category = Categories.query.filter_by(sno=sno).first()
    db.session.delete(category)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect('/viewcategories')

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Below is the code for viewcategories.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">
    <h3 class="mt-5">Categories</h3>

    {% if category|length == 0 %}
    
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <i class="bi bi-exclamation-triangle-fill"></i> No Records Found. Add your First Category!
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
    
    {% else %}
    
    {% for category in category %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card shadow mb-1 bg-white rounded">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">{{loop.index}}</div>
                        <div class="col">{{category.cat_type}}</div>
                        <div class="col">{{category.cat_group}}</div>
                        <div class="col">{{category.subcat}}</div>
                        <div class="col"><a href="/edit/{{category.sno}}" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#mymodaledit{{category['sno']}}">Edit</a></div>
                        <div class="col"><a href="/delete/{{category.sno}}" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete this category?');">Delete</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    
    {% endif %}
    
</div>

<!-- The Modal Edit -->

<div class="modal fade" id="mymodaledit{{category['sno']}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Category</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">

                    <!-- Update Category Tab -->

                    <div class="container"><br>
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            <div>
                                <h5 class="mt-3">Category Type</h5>
                                <input type="hidden" name="sno" id="" value="{{category.sno}}">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="cat_type" id="expense" value="{{category.cat_type}}">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="expense">
                                    Expense
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input class="form-check-input mt-1" type="radio" name="cat_type" id="income" value="{{category.cat_type}}">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="income">
                                    Income
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <h5 class="mt-3">Category Group</h5>
                                <input class="form-control mt-1" type="text" name="cat_group" id="cat_group" 
                                    value="{{category.cat_group}}">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <h5 class="mt-3">Sub Category</h5>
                                <input class="form-control mt-1" type="text" name="subcat" id="subcat" 
                                    value="{{category.subcat}}">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input class="btn btn-primary my-3" type="submit" value="Submit">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Below is the code for base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation Bar -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="Fourth navbar example">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Expand at md</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarsExample04"
                aria-controls="navbarsExample04" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link fs-4" aria-current="page" href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                            data-bs-target="#myModal"><i class="bi bi-plus-square"></i></a>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form role="search">
                    <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Shortcuts Links Container Row 1 -->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container col p-5 m-3 text-center border">
                <a href="/viewcategories"><i class="bi bi-plus-square fs-1"></i></a>
            </div>

            <div class="container col p-5 m-3 text-center border">
                <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-plus-square fs-1"></i></a>
            </div>

            <div class="container col p-5 m-3 text-center border">
                <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-plus-square fs-1"></i></a>
            </div>

            <div class="container col p-5 m-3 text-center border">
                <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-plus-square fs-1"></i></a>
            </div>

            <div class="container col p-5 m-3 text-center border">
                <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-plus-square fs-1"></i></a>
            </div>

            <div class="container col p-5 m-3 text-center border">
                <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-plus-square fs-1"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- The Modal -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- Modal Header -->

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add New</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container">

                        <!-- Nav tabs -->

                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Expense</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Income</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Transfer</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Category</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab5">Account</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <!-- Tab panes -->

                        <div class="tab-content">

                            <!-- Expense Tab -->

                            <div id="tab1" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
                                <form>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Date</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="date" name="expensedate" id="expensedate">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Remarks</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="expensename" id="expensename">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Amount</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="expenseamount" id="expenseamount">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Category</label>
                                        <select class="form-select" name="expensesubcat" id="expensesubcat">
                                            <option value="food">Food</option>
                                            <option value="transport">Transport</option>
                                            <option value="entertainment">Entertainment</option>
                                            <option value="others">Others</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Account</label>
                                        <select class="form-select" name="expenseaccount" id="expenseaccount">
                                            <option value="acc1">Acc 1</option>
                                            <option value="acc2">Acc 2</option>
                                            <option value="acc3">Acc 3</option>
                                            <option value="acc4">Acc 4</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
                                </form>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Income Tab -->

                            <div id="tab2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
                                <form>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Date</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="date" name="incomedate" id="incomedate">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Remarks</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="incomename" id="incomename">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Amount</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="incomeamount" id="incomeamount">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Category</label>
                                        <select class="form-select" name="incomesubcat" id="incomesubcat">
                                            <option value="food">Food</option>
                                            <option value="transport">Transport</option>
                                            <option value="entertainment">Entertainment</option>
                                            <option value="others">Others</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Account</label>
                                        <select class="form-select" name="incomeaccount" id="incomeaccount">
                                            <option value="acc1">Acc 1</option>
                                            <option value="acc2">Acc 2</option>
                                            <option value="acc3">Acc 3</option>
                                            <option value="acc4">Acc 4</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
                                </form>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Transfer Tab -->

                            <div id="tab3" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
                                <form>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Date</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="date" name="transferdate" id="transferdate">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Remarks</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="transfername" id="transfername">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Amount</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="transferamount"
                                            id="transferamount">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">From Account</label>
                                        <select class="form-select" name="transferfrom" id="transferfrom">
                                            <option value="acc1">Acc 1</option>
                                            <option value="acc2">Acc 2</option>
                                            <option value="acc3">Acc 3</option>
                                            <option value="acc4">Acc 4</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">To Account</label>
                                        <select class="form-select" name="transferto" id="transferto">
                                            <option value="acc1">Acc 1</option>
                                            <option value="acc2">Acc 2</option>
                                            <option value="acc3">Acc 3</option>
                                            <option value="acc4">Acc 4</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
                                </form>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Category Tab -->

                            <div id="tab4" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
                                <form action="/viewcategories" method="POST">
                                    <div>
                                        <h5 class="mt-3">Category Type</h5>
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="cat_type" id="expense" value="Expense"
                                            checked>
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="expense">
                                            Expense
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="form-check-input mt-1" type="radio" name="cat_type" id="income" value="Income">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="income">
                                            Income
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <h5 class="mt-3">Category Group</h5>
                                        <input class="form-control mt-1" type="text" name="cat_group" id="cat_group"
                                            placeholder="Add Category Group">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <h5 class="mt-3">Sub Category</h5>
                                        <input class="form-control mt-1" type="text" name="subcat" id="subcat"
                                            placeholder="Add Sub Category">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="btn btn-primary my-3" type="submit" value="Submit">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Account Tab -->

                            <div id="tab5" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
                                <form>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Payee</label>
                                        <select class="form-select" name="payee" id="payee">
                                            <option value="payee1">Payee 1</option>
                                            <option value="payee2">Payee 2</option>
                                            <option value="payee3">Payee 3</option>
                                            <option value="payee4">Payee 4</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Account</label>
                                        <select class="form-select" name="accountname" id="accountname">
                                            <option value="acc1">Acc 1</option>
                                            <option value="acc2">Acc 2</option>
                                            <option value="acc3">Acc 3</option>
                                            <option value="acc4">Acc 4</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal footer 

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>  -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Popper JavaScript -->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    {% block body %}

    {% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```